# UWP: Start menu tile text color

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

[image]

Is there a way to change the color of the text displayed under the UWP app tile in the start menu? I use a white background, and since the text is white too, the app's title is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past Metro application (Win8) development, [VisualElements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-visualelements?redirectedfrom=MSDN) provided a property `ForegroundText` to set the color of the tile title.

But in [VisualElements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-visualelements) of UWP, this attribute is not included, but it is still available.

So we can write:

**package.appxmanifest**

```xml
<uap:VisualElements
  ...
  ForegroundText="dark"
  BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
  <!-- other code -->
</uap:VisualElements>
```

This is not recommended. Since this attribute has not been declared, once you add this attribute, you will no longer be able to open the `package.appxmanifest` designer.

You can consider changing the design to avoid setting the tile background to pure white

Comment: It makes no sense to not allow white backgrounds, especially since black text will have the highest contrast possible. In this sense a pure black background should also not be desired. Furthermore the EPSON app in the image provided by the OP makes this even more clear.